# I want to extract a part of the string from a string using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have the variable $state="Mississippi Alabama Texas Massachusetts Kansas".
I wanna find the word which contains xas in the end and store this word in a array.I am trying for it, but no results:

```
<?php
$states="Mississippi Alabama Texas Massachusetss Kansas";
$str="/xa$/";
$string="";
$ee=preg_match( "/xas$/",$str,$matches);
echo $ee;
echo $matches;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use word break `\b` instead end-of-string (`$`) and you should also include the other characters of the word you try to match (with `\w*`):

```
$states="Mississippi Alabama Texas Massachusetss Kansas";
preg_match("/\w*xas\b/", $states, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

output:

```
Array( [0] => "Texas" )
```